# How to provide relative path of icon in PyInstaller while creating an exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a console based exe using pyinstaller using the following command.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --console -i icon/app.ico main.py
```

or

```
pyinstaller --onefile --console --icon=./icon/app.ico main.py
```

Pyinstaller creates the exe but it does not embed the icon which I have provided.
My icon file name is **app.ico and is located inside a folder called icon**.
Please help about how to do it.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Using Data Files from a Module](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it works, I mean this command `pyinstaller --onefile --console -i icon/app.ico main.py` works. There is a problem with icon cache, that is why it was not properly reflecting. Once exe is created, copy the exe file to a different location, it works and you can see the icon in the exe.